# cross fade delayed transition end event no accessible

Tags: animation, polymer, cross-fade

I am using cross-fade-delay transition in my polymer app, in order to play nicely with the hero transition: cross fade text after hero transition is finished.

I currently use the transition-end callback to trigger another operation (some javascript function call). Problem is that this call is a bit ressource expensive so it makes the cross-fade-delay transition lag.

transition-end call back is triggered after the hero transition is completed. Is there a similar event, to know when the cross-fade-delayed finished?

Best,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a similar event to monitor the end of the `cross-fade-delayed` transition animation.

However, a quick workaround is, inside the `on-core-animated-pages-transition-end` handler, call your js function after a simple delay of the duration of the `cross-fade-delayed` transition.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('animation transition completed!');
},
// convert for example 400ms to 400
parseInt(CoreStyle.g.transitions.xfadeDelay, 10));
```

You might even want to add between 50ms and 100ms to the delay on top of the `xfadeDelay` just to ensure the js function works smoothly on the UI.